# Quasiperiodic sequence, finite differences, recursion

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences, continued-fractions

Consider a sequence $\{an\}$ consisting of fractional parts of the numbers $an$ for natural numbers $n$ where $a$ is an irrational number. Its $n$th value is in the interval $(x;y)$ for numbers $n = n_1,n_2,\dots$. Consider the sequence of differences $n_2-n_1,n_3-n_2,\dots$.  It is a quasiperiodic sequence. Can one obtain it by recursive transformations of a string?

For example, the sequence of numbers $n$ such that $\{n\sqrt2\}$ is inside the interval $(0,0.2)$ is transformed into a sequence consisting of the lines "5 5 7 5 5 2", "5 5 7 5 7 5 5 2" and "5 5 7 5 7 5 5 7 5 7 5 5 2". If we denote them as 6, 8 and 13 respectively, we obtain the blocks of the form "6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 13", "6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 13" and "6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 6 8 6 8 6 13".  Has it been shown that one can continue this process indefinitely and always use at most 3 different types of blocks?

Comment: I'm not sure what "recursive transformations of a string" means. I'm not sure whether the "3 different types of blocks" question is just about $a=\sqrt2$ or is about all real irrational $a$.

Comment: For quadratics I think this should follow from periodicity of the continued fraction for $\alpha$.

Comment: The question is about all real irrational numbers a. The example shows that the finite differences are arranged into strings of three kinds. These strings themselves form a quasiperiodic sequence which also turns out to be composed of blocks of three types.

Comment: UPD: I also observed this behaviour for irrational numbers like $e$ and $\pi$.

Comment: What is $x$? What is $y$? What is $n_1,n_2,\dots$? I don't understand the process being described.

Comment: @Ben, my interpretation is that $(x,y)$ is a subinterval of $(0,1)$, and $n_k$ is the $k$ smallest positive integer $n$ such that the fractional part of $an$ lies in $(x,y)$.